Не открывается MsConfig
Я столкнулся с неприятной проблемой - у меня не открывается msconfig.
Windows 10. При открытии msconfig через Win + R или через проводник(с правами администратора) он открывается, но открывается лишь на некоторое время и сразу же закрывается. Никаких ошибок не вылезает. Никаких ошибок с файлами не смог обнаружить с помощью sfc /scannow.
Знаю, что можно решить переустановкой винды, но не хочется как-то.

Вирусы?! Автономная проверка на вирусы вроде Kaspersky Rescue Disk

Есть вариант создать нового пользователя.
У меня что-то похожее было, не запускался какой-то компонент. Запускался под одним из админов. У новых пользователей не запускался. Был битый профиль по умолчанию. Создал нового админа, зашёл им, убил профиль по умолчанию и сделал новый из работающего админского.

Спасибо большое! Сработало!
